# How to query on a Google Sheets to sort by month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm using this Sheetgo Attendance template on Google Sheets, but it's designed for US Schools so it's needed to sort by January to December. I will provide below the assets that I've have about it. Can someone help me with how to Query it?

Source (Google Drive): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aEdUYuKHlaiCrNZShSt20swEu7u13-z4?usp=sharing

[image: G-Sheets]

Source Data (Picture): [image: G-Sheets]

Where I need to edit the Query: 
[image: Cell H-17 on tab Data Preparation Charts]

The previous Query: =QUERY('Overview per month'!A:F,"SELECT A,AVG(B) GROUP BY A LABEL AVG(B) 'Presence rate'",1)

Comment: Welcome. That is a complicated, ready-made sheet by a company and you should NOT change the formulas since they are interlocked (except the ranges they refer to). Instead, read the instructions carefully and try to understand what they say.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer! I will temporarily do the data adjustments by simply adding VLOOKUPs and more columns. Do you believe it's impossible to do it with Query? My knowledge on this Google Query is super limited still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't order a query by month names because that would order them either alphabetically from A - Z or from Z - A. To achieve your ordering from January to December, you first need to create a mapping as follows:

```
1: January
2: February
...
12: December
```

Then you can order by month number to get the sorting correctly.